# Format/beautify bigquery code (like procedures)

Tags: google-bigquery, formatter

Do we have any tool to format/beautify bigquery code formatter?
Any standalone or open source code?
I did not find anything particular for big query.

Comment: SqlFluff does exactly that, and includes support for BigQuery https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff . We use it in our CI pipeline to ensure folks are committing code that adheres to sqlfluff’s rules.

Comment: Sorry, just realised you need it for stored procedure code too. SqlFluff only supports SQL, not procedural code.

Answer (score 4):

Go to BQ console.
Under more there is an option of format query.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm looking for a standalone or api to format all the big query code. Is that possible ?

Comment: Try this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh

Comment: this was for classic UI which is obsolete as we all know. I never had chance to bring it to Console UI, and not planning :o) rather try new tools - check links in my profile